# Loading translation files on demand

Tags: reactjs, i18next

A standard approach for translation using i18next usually involves loading all the translation files at once, as soon as the web app is loaded.

i.e

```
i18n
    .use(XHR)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .init({
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        debug: false,

        keySeparator: false,

        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
            formatSeparator: ','
        },

        resources: {
            en: {
                translations: en
            },
            ru: {
                translations: ru
            },
            es: {
                translations: es
            }
        },

        ns: ['translations'],
        defaultNS: 'translations',

        react: {
            wait: true
        }
});
```

I find this approach quite inefficient and would like to request translation files from the server as needed (i.e when the client switches the language). Unfortunately, I didn't find any reference to that in the official documentation but there certainly should be a way of accomplishing this.

*Schema of what I want to achieve:*

1) Web app loads along with **only** default translation file (e.g `english.json`)

2) If the user switches the language – let's say to Spanish – `spanish.json` is being loaded from the server and the whole translation is adjusted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [API documentation](https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options) for the `.init()` method's configuration options:

> partialBundledLanguages — allows some resources to be set on initialization while others can be loaded using a backend connector

So, setting the option to true will achieve what you're aiming for.